Calculating lattice constant using QE with ASE
I'm trying to follow simple example of determining the lattice constant (https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/tutorials/eos/eos.html), but using QE instead of EMT. Here is ASE code I use:
import numpy as np
from ase.build import bulk
from ase.calculators.espresso import Espresso, EspressoProfile
from ase.io.trajectory import Trajectory
from ase.io.espresso import write_espresso_in

from ase.units import kJ

import os

pseudo_dir = '/mnt/d/PhD/DFT/SSSP_1.3.0_PBE_efficiency'
profile = EspressoProfile(
    command='mpirun -n 2 /home/mateja/qe-7.3.1/bin/pw.x',
    pseudo_dir=pseudo_dir
) 
input_data = {
    'prefix': 'Ag_lattice',
    'pseudo_dir': pseudo_dir,
    'outdir': '/mnt/d/PhD/DFT/LatticeConstant',
    'calculation': 'scf',
    'restart_mode': 'from_scratch',
    'tprnfor': True,
    'etot_conv_thr': 1e-5,
    'forc_conv_thr': 1e-4,
    'ecutwfc': 60,
    'ecutrho': 480,
    'input_dft': 'rpbe',
    'vdw_corr': 'dft-d3',
    'occupations': 'smearing',
    'degauss': 0.01,
    'smearing': 'gaussian',
    'conv_thr': 1e-8,
    'mixing_mode': 'local-TF',
    'mixing_beta': 0.35,
    'diagonalization': 'david',
    'ion_dynamics': 'bfgs',
    'bfgs_ndim': 6,
    'startingwfc': 'random',
}

pseudopotentials = {
    'Ag': 'Ag_ONCV_PBE-1.0.oncvpsp.upf'  # Ensure this file is in the pseudo_dir
}

def run_espresso(atoms, prefix, input_pars):

    calc = Espresso(profile=profile, pseudopotentials=pseudopotentials, tstress=True, tprnfor=True,input_data=input_pars, kpts=(1, 1, 1))
    atoms.calc = calc
    # Write the input file
    input_file = f'{prefix}.in'
    output_file = f'{prefix}.out'
    write_espresso_in(input_file,atoms, input_pars, pseudopotentials=pseudopotentials, format='espresso-in')

    return atoms.get_potential_energy()


a = 4.0  
ag = bulk('Ag', 'fcc', a=a)
traj = Trajectory('Ag.traj', 'w', atoms=ag)
for x in np.linspace(0.95, 1.05, 5):
    run_espresso(ag, 'Ag_lattice', input_data)
    traj.write(ag)
    
    
from ase.eos import EquationOfState
from ase.io import read
from ase.units import kJ

configs = read('Ag.traj@0:5')

volumes = [ag.get_volume() for ag in configs]
energies = [ag.get_potential_energy() for ag in configs]
eos = EquationOfState(volumes, energies)
v0, e0, B = eos.fit()
print(B / kJ * 1.0e24, 'GPa')
eos.plot('Ag-eos.png',show=False)

Why are my results so off?


EMT is an interatomic potential (see here). QE does plane-wave DFT, which is expected to be more accurate than an interatomic potential because of explicit treatment of the electrons in a quantum mechanical way. So, they should give you different-ish answers. You could check what the experimental lattice constant of fcc-Ag is and compare with what you get from EMT and QE (via the EOS analysis).

That being said, there are various things you could change within DFT that will affect the outcome. E.g. why are you using a D3 correction ('vdw_corr': 'dft-d3') for bulk silver? Your single k-point kpts=(1, 1, 1) might not be sufficiently converged.

I am not going to have the time to write a full answer right now, but D3 must be included for bulk silver if they will use D3 later for a surface calculation for example.  You can't get a lattice without D3 then use it with D3 later.

Also, (1, 1, 1) kpt grid is definitely incorrect.  I would expect at least a (12, 12, 12) for a primitive cell of Ag to be needed.

Thank you for your answer, bigger kpts grid definitely gives better results
